# Java: How to wait for fileChanged to execute?

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io, concurrency, file-monitoring

I'd like to have my thread (the main/EDT) wait until changes to a file occur and then wait. DefaultFileMonitor extends Runnable and hence runs in a thread of its own. Here is a SSCE:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.commons.vfs.*;
import org.apache.commons.vfs.impl.DefaultFileMonitor;

public class FileChangeListener implements FileListener {
    DefaultFileMonitor fm;
    public final static File logFile = new File("t.txt");

 public void startListening() throws FileSystemException {
    final FileSystemManager fsManager = VFS.getManager();
    final FileObject listendir = fsManager.toFileObject(logFile);

    fm = new DefaultFileMonitor(this);
    fm.addFile(listendir);
    fm.start();
}

     @Override
public void fileCreated(FileChangeEvent fce) throws Exception {
    fileChanged(fce);
}

@Override
public void fileDeleted(FileChangeEvent fce) throws Exception {
    //hmm..why deleted?
}

@Override
public void fileChanged(FileChangeEvent fce) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("fileChanged executed");
}
}
```

The main:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileChangeListener fcl = new FileChangeListener();
    try {
        fcl.startListening();
        final PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(FileChangeListener.logFile);
        printWriter.println("Hello Threads!");
        printWriter.close();

        //EXECUTE THE FOLLOWING ONLY AFTER fileChanged
        System.out.println("Mission complete.");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append the following to App.main(..) after printWriter.close():

```
            synchronized (fcl) {
                fcl.wait();
            }
            //EXECUTE THE FOLLOWING ONLY AFTER fileChanged
            System.out.println("Mission complete.");
```

and append the following to FileChangeListener.fileChanged(..) after System.out.println("fileChanged executed"):

```
synchronized (this) {
        this.notifyAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could communicate between teh two using "Conditions" : http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html

Basically, create a new "shared" `Condition` (say `fileChanged`). Now, whenever the file changes (in `fileChanged()` trigger this condition (`fileChanged.signal()`). In your main code, wait for this condition to occur (`fileChanged.await()`).

Hope you get the idea.

---

For making the condition accessible to multiple code unit, here is what I can think (decreasing order of preference) :

1. Assuming you are going to need as many conditions as many files you listen to, create a factory method `getCondition(String file path/name/attribute)` which will return the `Condition` object based on the file (its path or name or other attributes). Use this factory method to get the condition in all cases. The factory should internally create `new Condition()` instances for each new file to be listened to AND must throw away older instances as the processing of the files is complete (so probably you should add a `destroy/deleteCondition(String file)` method as well.)
2. Store the condition as a `public` field in the listener class (kind of hack if you have the listener instance available).
3. Store the condition as a `public static` field in the listener class (kind of hack if you have only one listener instance throughout).

Comment: any example code (beside the one given in the javadoc)? How do I share Condition, making it public?

Comment: Assuming code for using the `Condition` is clear, for making the condition accessible to multiple code unit, see answer edit.

Comment: could u alter the sample code to include your answer as I did in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Why? FileChangeListener is a *callback:* it is executed *when the event occurs.* In this specific case you've just closed the file so you alreayd know that the mission is complete on that file, so just proceed to the next step. I don't see why you need a FileChangeListener at all here.

Comment: This is just the code you posted that I commented on. If you want to post the real code, I will comment on that too.